# How to get a image form datagridview and send to other datagridview c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I wanted to see if anyone could help me see how to correctly abstract an image by
selecting it from a datagridview and when it is saved I can send it to another datagridview using c#
and mysql.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCskh.png)

Here we can see the datagridview where we have elements id, name, price and an image. With this line
of code I managed to get the name and price of the product or item, and to be able to pass it through
a query to my other datagridview.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thb3q.png)

And now these are some attempts to be able to obtain the image of the datagridview and to be able to
put it in a byte[] to be able to send it to the other datagridview.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6P1M.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XQEv.png)

And this is one of the errors I've been given when running the get the image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUOeq.png)

I would appreciate seeing if anyone has any ideas on how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Help people help you by posting code as actuall text and not as images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to to convert your byte array to image first. Try

```
using(MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream(byteArray)
{
   Image image=Image.FromStream(ms);
   return image;
}
```

Comment: Hey man, but how can I do it if that "method" using is receiving as parameter the array the aByte try to do it that way but I don't understand what you mean it would be very helpful if you could explain me a little more. Thank you very much in advance.